# {$foo|@print_r} prints '{$foo|@print_r}' on the screen

Tags: php, smarty

I want to print array variable  `$foo`. So I have done `{$foo|@print_r}` this but its prints like `"{$foo|@print_r}"` on the front page.

I'm using the Oxied eshop and its use smarty as a template engine.

Comment: this work fore me .
{$foo|@print_r}
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try at least: that the array print for php in common

```
<?php
     print_r ($foo);
?>
```

Else try something like:

```
<?php
     {$foo|@debug_print_var} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by using smarty in smarty variable, and `{eval $foo|@debug_print_var}` should print output.